# How to use emoticon icon in HTML in following scenario?

Tags: html, emoticons

I've following HTML code :

```
<div id="js_contact_message">Your have been registered successfully</div>
```

With the following emoticon after the word "successfully":
[image]

How to achieve this?

I got following link but not understanding how to make use of these unicode values?

```
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode
```

Comment: Why not just use a normal `<img>` tag? As the referenced page says, most desktop browsers won't display most emoji natively using unicode values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```css
#js-contact-message:after {
content: '\1f603';
color:orange; /* yellow: not enough contrast with white background */
}
```

```html
<div id="js-contact-message">… successfully</div>
```

Comment: The emoticon icon is appearing in black color, I want it in yellow color.

Comment: @PHPLover: so use the `color` CSS property to style it?

Comment: But I don't know how to use it? Can you please add it to your answer? It would be really helpful to me.

Comment: I've updated the answer. As Rhumborl says, browser support may be sketchy.